# How to merge repeating node values into one node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <table>
        <items>Item 1</items>
    </table>
    <table>
        <items>Item 2</items>
    </table>
    <table>
        <items>Item 3</items>
    </table>
    <table>
        <items>Item 4</items>
    </table>
</root>
```

I want to merge all items values into one node so I can use that nodes value in some piece of code.

The end result should look like this:

```
<root>
    <table>
        <items>Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4</items>
    </table>
</root>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You've tagged [tag:c#] and [tag:linq] but there's no such code here. What have tried? Focus on "a way" first; you can work toward the "best way" later.

Comment: I suspect that the best way would be to combine the values in the code instead of in the XML. If you were to alter the XML then you would be losing information.

Comment: Well I'm new to this and this is the XML I have to work with. Need all values in one node and need to use C# for that before I can use that information in a further step in the process

Comment: Do you need all the values in one node in a new XML file (and note that adding commas and spaces makes them not the same values) or would it be more useful to you to have the values in a List<string>, or would you like them in a string variable without all the surrounding XML?

Comment: I need to convert my current xml (see first code block) to a new XML file that looks like the second code block I posted. The new XML will be an input for a process

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
     var newXml = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("root",
                       new XElement("table",
                          new XElement("items", 
        XDocument.Parse(xml)
           .Descendants()
           .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("table"))
           .Select(x => x.Element("items").Value)
           .Aggregate((x, y) => string.Join(", ", x, y))))));
```

Comment: I'll try this when I'm home tnx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, tried multiple solutions.

I ended up with the following solution:

```
    var input = "XML";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

    XElement root = doc.Root;
    XElement parentTable = root.Element("parentTable");
    parentTable.Add(new XElement("components"));
    XElement components = parentTable.Element("components");
    ArrayList componentArray = new ArrayList();

    foreach (var d in doc.Descendants("table"))

    {
        componentArray.Add(d.Value + ", ");
    }

    components.Add(componentArray);

    doc.Save("XML");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            List<XElement> children = root.Elements().ToList();
            string[] items = root.Descendants("items").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    children[i].Element("items").ReplaceWith(new XElement("items", string.Join(",", items)));
                }
                else
                {
                    children[i].Remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```